# Closing the parent window when opening a child window in wx python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have written a code to open a file chooser and select html files. when a user selects a html file it will be displayed in a web viewer but I need to close the previous window which I used to  open the file chooser when the html page is displayed in the web view.

I have tried making the FileChooserframe.Close() after the webpage is displayed on the webview

```
import os
import wx
import wx.html2
import facial_expression_recognition_from_stream
import csvReader

FileFilter = "Html files (*.html)|*.html|" \
             "All files (*.*)|*.*"

class UXEvaluationApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Choose a html file")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()

        openFileDlgBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Choose a HTML File")
        openFileDlgBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFile)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(openFileDlgBtn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onOpenFile(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Choose a html file", defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, defaultFile="", wildcard=FileFilter, style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            htmlFilePath = dlg.GetPath()

            FileChooserframe.Close()
            myBrowserInstance = MyBrowser(None, -1)
            myBrowserInstance.browser.LoadURL(htmlFilePath)
            myBrowserInstance.Show()
            facial_expression_recognition_from_stream.main()
            FileChooserframe.Close()

        dlg.Destroy()

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        button = wx.Button(self, label="Complete Tracking", pos=(20, 70))
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getReport)
        self.SetSize((700, 700))

    def getReport(self, event):
        facial_expression_recognition_from_stream.stop()
        frame = Report()
        frame.Show()


class Report(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self):
        csvReader.showReport()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    FileChooserframe = UXEvaluationApp()
    FileChooserframe.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I need FileChooserFrame to be closed on onOpenFile method

Comment: `Close()` should work. Have you tried `Destroy()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filechooser that closes once the user chooses a file:

From: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileDialog.html

```
with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz",
                       style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

        if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return     # the user changed their mind

        # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
        pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
        try:
            with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                self.doLoadDataOrWhatever(file)
        except IOError:
            wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)
```

On the other hand, you cannot close the main frame without closing the other frames that depend on it. But you can **Hide()** it. To show it again, simply call **myframe.Show()**

Good luck.